# How to remove commented line

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

Please advise how can i run time delete the commented out code /* .. */ in my Store Procedure. Taking example below: If my SP has found a junk of commented code in this way below, all the commented code will be deleted  including the commented sign.

```
/*
    INSERT INTO MATERIAL.GTT_DMD
      (
      asof_src_dt
      , asof_src_tm
      )
        SELECT
       asof_src_dt
       , CAST (asof_src_ts AS  TIME(0)) AS asof_src_tm
     FROM  DEMAND.v_supl SNP_DMD
*/
```

---

Thanks for the support, i found the Regex

```
/\*[\w\W]*?(?=\*/)\*/
```

Can you help to review if this is the best way of deleting the code. Thanks.

```
public void DeleteCommentedCode(string filePath)
    {
        StreamReader input = new StreamReader(filePath);

        Regex pattern = new Regex("/\*[\w\W]*?(?=\*/)\*/");            

          StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath + ".tmp");

        while (!streamReader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string data = streamReader.ReadLine();
            if(pattern.IsMatch(data))
            {
                data = data.Replace(data, ""); // Replace with empty 
                streamWriter.WriteLine(data);
            }

        }

        streamReader.Close();
        streamWriter.Close();
    }
```

Comment: where is the commented code in above query? you want delete the commented code from C#?

Comment: @belinq sorry for my ninja edits please do it yourself...

Comment: @Anandkumar: basically is to delete the whole junk of code commented code at run time.

Comment: I believe the word you're looking for is "chunk", as in "chunk of code"

Comment: HI, i updated my question with the solution above. Can anyone please review to see if that is the correct way of doing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean remove comments from stored procedure, there is a post on here about extracting SP content.

[C#/SQL Get all Stored Procedures and their Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549794/c-sql-get-all-stored-procedures-and-their-code)

To remove the comments you could try using a regular expression, there is a good article here on cleaning SQL Statments with some RegEx examples.

http://larrysteinle.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/use-regular-expressions-to-clean-sql-statements/

Comment: Thanks for your post. I found the regex there. I have edited my post with my latest solution. Can you verify. Thansk.